# Finding ring homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Three questions. Looking to find all ring homomorphism from Z6 to Z2. and Z2 to Z. and Z2 to Z6 And definition for ring homomorphism requires that 1 goes to 1.

So since the integers are made by 1. Does this imply that for each of these there is only the trivial homomorphism? Any help or hints would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If such a homomorphism $f$ exists, it must satisfy $f(1) = 1$ and $f(n) = nf(1) = n$. Therefore there is at most one homomorphism. In each case, determine whether this homomorphism is well-defined.

Comment: So for Z6 to Z2. this is not well defined since f(1+1)=2 but in Z2 f(1+1)=0? SImiarly for Z2 to Z6? then for Z2 to Z there is still only one since f(1+1)=0 and in Z f(1+1)=2??

Comment: @JacobRodgers That's not a problem for $\mathbb{Z}_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ since $0 = 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. However it is indeed a problem the other way around, and it is also a problem if the codomain if $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, observe there aren't very many of these homomorphisms around:

> **Proposition 0.** Consider a number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. For all rings $R$, there is at most one homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$.
>
> (In other words, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is "epi-initial" in the category of rings, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092122/is-there-an-accepted-term-for-those-objects-of-a-category-x-such-that-for-all)).

Existence is answered by:

> **Proposition 1.** Consider a number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. For all rings $R$, there exists a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ iff for all $r \in R$ we have $nr = 0$.

You should be able to use this to prove the following:

> **Proposition 2.** For all numbers $n,r \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ iff $r \mid n$.